# Как заставить php разрешать пути через htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть файл `.htaccess` в корневом каталоге сайта, в котором, среди прочего указаны следующие перенаправления:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)\/([1-9][0-9]*\/)?([a-z]*|[1-9][0-9]*\/)*$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ([^\/]*)\.js$ public/scripts/$1.js [L]
```

HTML их прекрасно учитывает, то есть скрипты, расположенные в `public/scripts/`, подключаются с любой страницы сайта следующим образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ion.sound.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="illtree.js"></script>
```

А вот PHP следующий код:

```
require_once "script.js";
```

Считает указанием искать файл в той же директории, что и тот, в который производится вставка, ничего там, разумеется, не находя, из-за чего приходится передавать функции абсолютный путь к файлу:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/public/scripts/script.js";
```

Что не слишком удобно, с точки зрения архитектуры: если я, по каким-то причинам, захочу переместить скрипты в другое место, то столкнусь с необходимостью править пути в нескольких местах, вместо того, чтобы просто обновить файл `.htaccess`. Можно ли как-то изменить это поведение, чтобы `.htaccess` перенаправлял запросы и от php-скриптов?

Comment: С каких пор .htaccess стал перехватывать подключение файлов внутри php? Это фантастика!

Comment: @Visman а предложить ему послать внешний запрос - никак? Пробовал скармливать `require` url - не помогло.

Comment: О каком внешнем запросе вы говорите? Вы загружаете `script.js` с чужого сервера?

Comment: @Visman со своего, но хочу, чтобы он обрабатывался так же, как и запросы клиента, по крайней мере - для данной ситуации.

Comment: Напишите функцию php, которая будет дергать нужный вам файл по его имени и тому пути к которому обратился пользователь. P.S. Вот эта команда `require_once "script.js";` будет подключать файл из той же директории в которой лежит файл где данная команда прописана.

Comment: @Visman да, вы правы, я просто неверно задал относительный путь, сейчас поправлю вопрос. Оформите свой первый комментарий, как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: чего вы вообще хотите добиться, подключая `JS`-файл в `require_once`? Вы понимаете что это директива для подключения других php-файлов, и она вообще никак не связана с `<script src=".."></script>`? зы: что бы не изменять пути в разных файлах обычно создают конфигурационные файлы, где определяют константы для путей, а-ля `BASE_DIR`, `TEMPLATES_DIR` и т.д.

Comment: @teran нет никаких технических ограничений, мешающих подгружать таким способом html или js. А добиться я хочу (и уже добился) вынесения всех скриптов из шаблона в отдельные файлы.

Comment: @Risto вы бы лучше шаблоны нормальные сделали с помощью smarty Или других движков, тогда бы и вопросов таких не было. `htaccess` вам вообще в данном вопросе никак не поможет, т.к. mod_rewrite предназначен для фильтрации входящих `http` запросов. Делайте либо конфиги с путями, либо папку скриптов включайте в `include_path` в настройках php.

Comment: зы, поставил минус вопросу, ибо это лютый пример говнокода или подхода.

Comment: @teran чем я пользуюсь или не пользуюсь к теме вопроса отношения не имеет. А за `include_path` спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP обращается к локальным файлам напрямую, а не через сервер, за перенаправление запросов к которому отвечает файл `.htaccess`. Однако, начиная с версии PHP 4.3.0 можно запрашивать с помощью функций `require` и `include` удалённые файлы, передав в качестве параметра url, вот так:

```
require_once "http://example.com/script.js";
```

Для работы подобных вызовов необходимо, чтобы такое поведение было разрешено в настройках PHP вашего сервера (параметры [`allow_url_include`](http://php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) и [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)). Однако, следует помнить, что такие правки в конфиге снижают защищённость сервера, поэтому их следует избегать.

Второй способ - включить директории, содержащие файлы для подключения в директиву настроек PHP [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.include-path), или использовать функцию [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-include-path.php), для изменения данной настройки на время выполнения текущего скрипта - например, добавив её в подключаемый ко всем файлам вашего сайта конфиг.